# NullPointerException при вызове метода

Tags: java, исключения

Имеется класс с несколькими методами:

```
public class StartAndGo implements Runnable{   
    public JTextArea infArea;

    private void startPoolThreads(int countThreads){
        int countCore = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if((countThreads<0) || (countThreads>countCore)){
            appendInTextArea("Enter the number of threads from 1 to "+countCore); //Первый вызов метода
        }else{
            StartAndGo theJob = new StartAndGo();
            for(int i=0;i<countThreads;i++){
                Thread t = new Thread(theJob);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getIPAddresses(){
        appendInTextArea("Getting IP-addresses from file..."); //Второй вызов метода
        ...
    }

    synchronized void appendInTextArea(String t){
        infArea.append(t);
    }
}
```

Метод appendInTextArea добавляет текстовое сообщение в текстовое поле на форме.
Так вот, при вызове метода appendInTextArea из метода startPoolThreads - текстовое сообщение добавляется в текстовое поле, а при вызове из getIPAddresses - исключение:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.parse.webdriver.StartAndGo.appendInTextArea(StartAndGo.java:134)
    at com.parse.webdriver.StartAndGo.getIPAddresses(StartAndGo.java:86)
    at com.parse.webdriver.StartAndGo.run(StartAndGo.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Инициализация infArea, метод buildGUI находится в классе StartAndGo:

```
private void buildGUI(){
        ...     
        infArea = new JTextArea(3,25);
        infArea.setLineWrap(true);
        infArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(infArea);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        panel.add(scroller);
        ...     
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Не могу понять, почему не работает вызов метода во втором случае?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class StartAndGo implements Runnable{   
    public JTextArea infArea;

    private void startPoolThreads(int countThreads){
        int countCore = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        if((countThreads<0) || (countThreads>countCore)){
            appendInTextArea("Enter the number of threads from 1 to "+countCore); //Первый вызов метода
        }else{
            StartAndGo theJob = new StartAndGo(); //!!!Создание нового экземпляра StartAndGo
                        //Т.к. это новый объект, у него infArea = null, 
                        //и он ничего не знает о infArea, который Вы создали в main (при вызове buildGUI)
            theJob.infArea = this.infArea; //Соответственно здесь нужно новому экземпляру передать infArea уже созданный 
                        //(либо создайте сами, исходя из требований)
            for(int i=0;i<countThreads;i++){
               Thread t = new Thread(theJob);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getIPAddresses(){
        appendInTextArea("Getting IP-addresses from file..."); //Второй вызов метода
        ...
    }

    synchronized void appendInTextArea(String t){
        infArea.append(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавил в вопрос инициализацию.

Comment: Когда новый объект создается `StartAndGo theJob = new StartAndGo();` у него вызывается `buildGUI` ? или как-то присваивается ему `infArea` ?

Comment: в методе main - new StartAndGo().buildGUI();
в buildGUI ActionListener на кнопку стоит, по нажатию которой дёргается метод startPoolThreads

Comment: В main понятно Вы инициализируете, но у вас в `startPoolThreads`  создание объекта идет, у которого также надо инициализировать `infArea` (полагаю именно в потоке вы потом и получаете ошибку с null от этого нового объекта)

Comment: Именно в пототке

Comment: @Cenzor, я обновил ответ, смотрите комментарии, не знаю как еще пояснить :-) что поток у Вас работает с новым объектом, в котором у Вас `infArea` не инициализирован, и получаем ошибку `NullPointerException`

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло, в каждом потоке прописал инициализацию infArea.